# How to convert a string with mathematical symbols into a number?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a calculator with JS. Is there a way to convert a string like `var calculation = "11+34*6"` into a "number" so JS can print out the solution?

Comment: you can use eval function. `var x = eval("2+2");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval()` function to solve your calculation even it is a string.

```js
let calculation = '11+34*6';
let result = eval(calculation);

document.write(result);
```

For better understanding read the documentation on Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript [`eval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function, that allows you to evaluate or execute a string argument, *e.g.*

```js
console.log(eval("11 + 34 * 6"));
```